# Create a block Most popular content using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, authentication-authorization

Can anyone explain how to create a block of most popular contents using google analytics. I know about the modules [Google Analystics Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga_stats) and [Most Popular](https://www.drupal.org/project/mostpopular) but there is no good documentation about this.

How can I get any of these module to work?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, an alternative option is the [radioactivity](https://www.drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking (also) at the [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides graphical reporting of your site's tracking data. Graphical reports include a dashboard widget for admins, a small path-based report in blocks, and a full path-based report.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this module depends on OAuth module which is an implementation of OAuth 1.0 standard . Google does not support OAuth 1.0 anymore

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [documentation](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/analyze-this-using-the-google-analytics-api) from Lullabot team